# How can I delay call lambda function with dynamic time

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, cron, aws-step-functions, aws-event-bridge

I trying to call a lambda function in dynamic delay time from another lambda function. For example, when you get a message with "success" in A lambda function, it will call B lambda function in one minute.

I don't want to use settimeout as I can't afford paying for sleep time in lambda.

I have found couple of solutions that are using Event Bridge, Step function and cloudwatch. However, all of these are using fixed delay time instead of dynamic delay time. What I mean by dynamic delay time is to call B lambda function with a time I set on the code which can be manipulated. As the solutions above set the time on their definition or configuration, I am not able to access and modify it on the code.

Please save me

Comment: You can create in Lambda A a cloudwtach event to trigger lambda B at the time you want (time now + delay). Did I miss something here?

Comment: If I delay it in lambda A, I have to pay for sleep time and I can't afford it. That's the main problem I have now. No money no solution

Comment: If Lambda A creates the cloudwatch event, then Lambda A can stop. The cloudwatch event will trigger Lambda B when the time has passed. The Lambda A would not be running until Lambda is triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the delay time is dynamic, we can use [Message Timers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-message-timers.html) options in SQS.

What you have to do is, place a SQS instance in-between Lambda A and Lambda B. Then the Lambda A should place a message in the queue along with the   [DelaySeconds](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_SendMessage.html) specified (Then that message will not visible in the queue until that specified DelaySeconds elapsed).

Then add that [SQS as a trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-configure-lambda-function-trigger.html) to Lambda B. So what happen is, the message placed by Lambda A will visible in the queue after the DelaySeconds passed. Then it will invoke the Lambda B.

Please note that, the maximum value which we can specify for DelaySeconds is 900 (15 mins). So this will not work if you need more delay than that.

Answer (score 0):

With Step Functions, the wait time can be dynamic. You do this using the SecondsPath or TimestampPath fields. With Step Functions Standard Workflows, your workflow execution can run / wait for up to a year. And you are not charged by the time you wait, just for the state transitions in the workflow.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-wait-state.html

Here's an example of what this might look like. First a placeholder Python lambda function that just returns a random integer for timeToWait:

```
import random

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    wait_time = random.randint(1,20)

    return {
        'timeToWait': wait_time
    }
```

Which can be included into a workflow like so. The delay between Lambda function invocation is dynamic based on the time returned from the Lambda function.

```
{
  "StartAt": "Lambda Function 1",
  "States": {
    "Lambda Function 1": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "OutputPath": "$.Payload",
      "Parameters": {
        "Payload.$": "$",
        "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:111111111111:function:PlaceholderFunction"
      },
      "Retry": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "Lambda.ServiceException",
            "Lambda.AWSLambdaException",
            "Lambda.SdkClientException",
            "Lambda.TooManyRequestsException"
          ],
          "IntervalSeconds": 2,
          "MaxAttempts": 6,
          "BackoffRate": 2
        }
      ],
      "Next": "Wait"
    },
    "Wait": {
      "Type": "Wait",
      "Next": "Lambda Function 2",
      "SecondsPath": "$.timeToWait"
    },
    "Lambda Function 2": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "OutputPath": "$.Payload",
      "Parameters": {
        "Payload.$": "$",
        "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:111111111111:function:PlaceholderFunction:$LATEST"
      },
      "Retry": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "Lambda.ServiceException",
            "Lambda.AWSLambdaException",
            "Lambda.SdkClientException",
            "Lambda.TooManyRequestsException"
          ],
          "IntervalSeconds": 2,
          "MaxAttempts": 6,
          "BackoffRate": 2
        }
      ],
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```